# How to perform group function basis a multiple columns and conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input data frame:

```
Order Id Part Name Ordered Date Supplier   PO Value Part Value Last PO - Diff
30501   7-AUTO GLOW 30-Aug-19   0884 SUN  398,310    19,200     Nan
28349   7-AUTO GLOW  4-Sep-19   0884 SUN  787,405    24,300     5
10556   7-AUTO GLOW 03-Nov-19   0884 SUN  426,767    84,240     60
22320   7-AUTO GLOW 07-Nov-19   0884 SUN   52,500    13,500     4
```

1. Group orders within 5 days together meaning (Row 0 and Row1) (Row 2 and Row3)`
2. Calculate the total value of the order (PO Value) and keep only above 1 million group

Output :

```
Order Id Part Name Ordered Date Supplier   PO Value Part Value Last PO - Diff
30501   7-AUTO GLOW 30-Aug-19   0884 SUN  398,310    19,200     Nan
28349   7-AUTO GLOW  4-Sep-19   0884 SUN  787,405    24,300     5
```